# How Can/Should I use Border Triangles in an HTML-Coded Email Blast?

Tags: html, css, html-email

Apologies for the 'off-the-wall' situation. I've long been a reader of stackoverflow.com, but I couldn't find my answer so I've decided to register and post. I've included a narrative so you can see my purposes for this type of layout that I'm trying to recreate.

In a job I've started, I was given an assignment to make an email blast that reflected this company's branding/logo theme throughout the layout for a large Lunch & Learn seminar for them to push their product and machinery.

They had a graphic designer already in place that has created something like this for a print flyer, which I've recreated visually in a fiddle as best/close as I can. Here it is:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lkopq5hw/2/

Here's the CSS that I threw in there for my example.

```
    .logoSection1 {
    background-color:blue;
    border-top: 600px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 600px solid transparent;
    border-left: 800px solid green;
    height: 800px; 
    width: 0; 
}
.logoSection2 {
    background-color:blue;
    border-top: 600px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 600px solid transparent;
    border-left: 800px solid green;
    height: 800px;
    width: 0; 

}
.tableBorder{
    border:1px solid black;
    width:800px;
}
```

---

I'm required to make the blast that takes the layout visually like this. I've never seen anything as unconventional (or modern?) as these shapes in an email, so I'm really at a loss as to how to do this with tables, but the only way I can make image-free (preferably) triangles for this layout is by way of a CSS hack I've learned through css-tricks back in March. However, I've used Divs and borders (Which I believe only causes a problem with Notes).

I need to put content (including markup, like anchors) in these triangles, but I can't do that without absolute positioning, from what I know of.

I was always told to stick to tables (not divs like I have), and I was taught that image maps are a bad idea. I'd really like to be able to identify which 'triangular' section is focused on, so I was going to track any of the links clicked inside of these 'sections' that the designer has created.

I'd really like to slap the designer in the face, but I also want to have a 'can-do' attitude for my new job. I really need to keep it, and I want to impress my superiors.

Here is some stuff I've found related to this, though none of the examples that I've seen have created the ability to put content INSIDE of the border triangles.

http://emailcodegeek.com/css-triangles/

-Edit-
I think I accidentally deleted half of my question. Retyped.

Comment: You should just use background images, coding email blasts is like developing a website in the 90s, it's highly doubtful that any sort of CSS-only version is going to be cross-client compatible. And yes, you should be using tables for eBlasts.

Comment: Tell them that this is not appropriate design for email ( which is true), and suggest something simpler... :)

Answer (score 0):

Tell your team that this is not possible to code for an email and explain to the designer impacts and issues incurred. Email design should be simple. code used should be very 90s - tables and inline coding, majority of the email browsers dont even read the css so as a coder you are very limited in what can be done. suggest using litmus for dev and testing, very handy tool for email development. Otherwise I would suggest setting a background with the entire graphic.

Answer (score 0):

I inlined your styles (using http://inliner.cm/) and ran it through Email on Acid for testing. This is what I got: https://www.emailonacid.com/app/acidtest/display/summary/dV6JrNFnonHBW5E2hQb3iOe8xgkDO1UeBjiIGkcUttTJN/shared

So it looks like your main issues are the Outlook desktop clients and Gmail. Sadly, that is a huge percentage of the market. If your superiors are OK with it looking bad on Live Mail, Lotus Notes, Outlook 2003, 2007, 2010,2013 and all Gmail clients, then keep on coding it for them. Otherwise I would do what user3767554 suggested and use an image background. Just be sure to [include VML](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/emailology_vector_markup_language_and_backgrounds) to get it working in Outlook for desktop.